# Process substitution with Perl script

Tags: bash, perl, process-substitution

I have a Perl [script](https://metacpan.org/release/Text-NSP/source/bin/count.pl) which requires the following arguments:

```
count.pl OUTPUT_FILE INPUT_FILE
```

What I want to do is to use process substitution instead of specifying INPUT_FILE explicitly, for instance:

```
count.pl count.txt <(cat test.txt)
```

However, it seems that the script does not receive any input from process substitution.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is the script doing with that second argument?

Comment: @Kusalananda `INPUT_FILE` is the text file which is the input to the script. Script process the `INPUT_FILE` and writes to the `OUTPUT_FILE`.

Comment: How does it process the input file? Does it read the file linearly as a stream, or does it try to search back and forth in the data?

Comment: @Kusalananda Script process file linearly (line 523).

Comment: Do you get an error message from the script?

Comment: No error message from the script, just empty `OUTPUT_FILE`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The script [uses `-T the-source-file`](https://metacpan.org/release/Text-NSP/source/bin/count.pl#L1003) to determine whether the file contains *text*.

That `-T` operator reads the start of the file and uses heuristics to determine whether it looks like text or not. But if the file is a pipe like in the `<(...)` case, then what it has read cannot be read again.

You can reproduce with:

```
$ perl -e '$file = shift; -T $file; open F, "<", $file; print while <F>' <(seq 1867)

1861
1862
1863
1864
1865
1866
1867
```

See how `-T` has consumed 8KiB from the output of `seq` which are no longer there for the `while <F>` loop to read.

Here, you could use zsh and its `=(...)` form of process substitution that uses a temporary file instead of a pipe. Or `(... | psub -f)` in the `fish` shell. Or remove that call to `-T` from that script. Or rewrite that script so it works with `<<>>`/`<>` (so it would also work on stdin when not passed any file argument) and outputs on stdout. I don't really see the point of it taking file names as arguments as it processes all of them in a stream fashion.

Comment: @user431397, for regular files, it's `-f`. `-T` works as documented, I see no bug in there.

Comment: @user431397, the script uses `<HANDLE>` on each file opened in turn, which like `<>` or `<<>>` reads one full record at a time. My suggestion of switching to `<>`/`<<>>` will make no difference in that regards.

Comment: @user431397, you'd have the same problem with `-T "/dev/fd/x"` even if x is a fd open on a regular file on systems other than Linux/Cygwin which would also have the side effect or moving the cursor within the file (`-T` could be modified to seek back in that case I suppose). `-T` would also be fine on other type of seekable files like block devices. The documentation is already clear that it does read from the file. Maybe it could give a warning that it makes little sense to use it on non-seekable files.

Comment: @user431397 Sorry you're right. I overlooked that `stat()` would not return +regular+ on /dev/fd/x on non-Limux (even if `fstar()` would on a FD opened on it)